# Using one ViewController with two tables in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have two tables in Xcode, the first table has many information and the second table has the same information but the it load only the favourite of the users.

What I need is If I am in the first Table to show details in DetailsViewController, and if I will go back it will take me back to the first table, If I am in the second Table I need to use the same DetailsViewController and also if i will go back it will take me to the second Table.

Can any one help me?
Hope the question is clear.

Comment: Are you using xibs or storyboard?

Comment: I am using storyboard